# How to print a double with a comma

Tags: c++, floating-point, double

In C++ I've got a float/double variable.

When I print this with for example cout the resulting string is period-delimited.

```
cout << 3.1415 << endl
$> 3.1415
```

Is there an easy way to force the double to be printed with a comma?

```
cout << 3.1415 << endl
$> 3,1415
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`imbue() cout` with a `locale` whose `numpunct` facet's `decimal_point()` member function returns a comma.

Obtaining such a `locale` can be done in several ways. You could use a named locale available on your system (`std::locale("fr")`, perhaps). Alternatively, you could derive your own numpuct, implement the `do_decimal_point()` member in it.

Example of the second approach:

```
template<typename CharT>
class DecimalSeparator : public std::numpunct<CharT>
{
public:
    DecimalSeparator(CharT Separator)
    : m_Separator(Separator)
    {}

protected:
    CharT do_decimal_point()const
    {
        return m_Separator;
    }

private:
    CharT m_Separator;
};
```

Used as:

```
std::cout.imbue(std::locale(std::cout.getloc(), new DecimalSeparator<char>(',')));
```

Comment: using your example results in: std::runtime error locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid

Comment: This error probably means that, on your platform, the "fr" name does not bind to a locale.

Comment: I guessed as much, but how could you find out which names *are* bound to a locale.

Comment: Sadly, I don't think there is a portable way.

Comment: do you know it for *nix perhaps?

Comment: On linux: the locale -a command, but I don't know how to do this programmatically.

Comment: programmatically retrieving the locale was no requirement, this works fine. And I guess anybody needing to do this programmatically could do some search-fu on a system() call. Thx! consider your answer accepted.

Answer (score 4):

This is controlled by your program's locale.

How you set a program's default locale depends on the platform.  On POSIX type platforms, it's with the LANG and LC_* environment variables, for instance.

You can force a particular locale -- different from the default -- within a C++ program by calling ios::imbue.  Something like this might work:

```
#include <locale>
cout.imbue(std::locale("German_germany"));
```

The idea is to force a locale where comma is the decimal separator.  You might need to adjust the "German_germany" string to get the behavior you want on your particular platform.

Comment: using your example results in: std::runtime error locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid

Answer (score 3):

You need to impue the stream with a different locale, one whose num_punct (iirc) facet specifies a comma.

If your platform locale formats with commas, then

```
cout.imbue(locale(""));
```

should be sufficient.

Comment: thx, your answer worked. But I'd like to accept an answer that will be more generic (if you're not so lucky with the correct locale presetup on your platform). Still +1 because it's the easiest method.

Answer (score 1):

To be precise, this is controlled by the `std::numpunct<charT>::decimal_point()` value. You can `imbue()` another locale with another `decimal_point()`

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but anyway ... One should be aware that using a `std::locale` makes the string "pretty", complete with correct decimal point, thousands separators and what not, depending on the platform and locale. Most probably, using `imbue()` will break any parsing of the string after it's formatted. For example:

```
std::ostringstream s;
std::locale l("fr-fr");
s << "without locale: " << 1234.56L << std::endl;
s.imbue(l);
s << "with fr locale: " << 1234.56L << std::endl;
std::cout << s.str();
```

Gives the following output:
`without locale: 1234.56`
`with fr locale: 1 234,56`

Using `strtod()` or similar on the second string probably won't work very well ... Also, the space between "1" and "2" in the second output string is a non-breaking one, making the string even prettier :-)

Answer (score 0):

Very old thread, but anyway ... I had the problem to fill a text entry under Gtkmm-3.0 with the outcome of a distance calculation. To make things clearer I add an example, where I have concentrated some wisdoms of several posts I read the last days:

```
#include <locale>
// next not necessary, added only for clarity
#include <gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm.h>
Gtk::Entry m_Text;
// a distance measured in kilometers
double totalDistance = 35.45678;
std::stringstream str;
// I am using locale of Germany, pay attention to the _
str.imbue(std::locale("de_DE"));
// now we have decimal comma instead of point
str << std::fixed << std::setprecision(4) << std::setw(16) << totalDistance << " km";
// the wished formatting corresponds to "%16.4f km" in printf
m_Text.set_text(str.str());
```